# TypeMismatchError: DOM Exception 17 when calling a function

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have the following code:

```
    if (nav == null) {
        nav = window.navigator;
    }
    var geoloc = nav.geolocation;
    if (geoloc != null) {
        watchID = geoloc.watchPosition(this.updatePosition(), this.locationNotFound());
    }
```

When this code executes I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: TypeMismatchError: DOM Exception 17
```

If I try and call the below in place of `watchId = ...` I get the same error:

```
geoloc.watchPosition()
```

This evening's coding session was going so well....

---

Seem's that I'm not retuning a function, rather calling a function in these cases. How can I correctly call the function in this situation?

Comment: Do `this.updatePosition()` and `this.locationNotFound()` really *return* functions? Or are you just confusing "pass a function" with "call a function"?

Comment: Think I might not be returning  function....

Comment: Not returning a function, how do I deal with this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you don't provide a callback. Here's an example :

```
watchID = geoloc.watchPosition(function(position) {
     console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
});
```

See [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation).

Comment: Why the downvote here ? And to OP what's not clear in my answer ?